# Make different lower and upper in mysql select

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to search for a name on database. But I just want select Bill , not biLL or BiLL or ... just "Bill". But when I use this query which shows Bill , BiLL, BILL, bilL and ...

```
query=`select * from names where name='Bill'`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/case-sensitivity.html):

> The default character set and collation are latin1 and latin1_swedish_ci, so nonbinary string comparisons are case insensitive by default. This means that if you search with col_name LIKE 'a%', you get all column values that start with A or a. To make this search case sensitive, make sure that one of the operands has a case sensitive or binary collation. For example, if you are comparing a column and a string that both have the latin1 character set, you can use the COLLATE operator to cause either operand to have the latin1_general_cs or latin1_bin collation

You can overcome this by explicitly using a case sensitive collation:

```
select * from names where name='Bill' COLLATE latin1_general_cs
```

Comment: thank you for the answer and the link. I had no idea how to resolve this.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But I want use query for login page and when i add COLLATE this will not work! I need other idea.

Answer (score -1):

There is also another solution to set the collection of the column to **utf8mb4_unicode_520** or any case sensitive standard collections.